# Solving UML in Java Scenario

Tags: java, inheritance, computer-science, composition, aggregation

I am a beginner level of studying java and revising for my exams through answering the questions on previous past exam papers and there is one question that I am stuck on.

**An OO design for a game has identified the following classes: GAME, LEVEL, CHARACTER, HERO, ENEMY and GAMEWORLD. HERO and ENEMY are both types of CHARACTER. A GAME takes place in a particular GAMEWORLD. A GAME has several LEVELS. Each LEVEL has a HERO CHARACTER and many ENEMY CHARACTERS that can appear and be removed.**

**Sketch a UML diagram for these classes in the scenario above, clearing showing the appropriate connectors between the classes. (There is no need to give any details in the class boxes.)**

I don't know how to draw UML connectors here but this is what I've answered:

***HERO and ENEMY are related to Character via Inheritance***

***GAME and LEVEL are related via Composition***

***LEVEL is related to HERO and ENEMY via Aggregation***

***GAME is related to GAMEWORLD via Inheritance***

I would appreciate it if someone can check for me if these answers are correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Almost right. Game does not inherit from GameWorld. GameWorld has an Aggregation pointing into Game (it's a one-to-many relation).

Answer (score 1):

Correct except for the GAME and GAMEWORLD relationship.

- HERO and ENEMY both inherit from CHARACTER => **Inheritance**
- GAME contains LEVELS but a level cannot exist without a game => **Composition**
- LEVEL can contain a HERO character and several ENEMY characters but it can also be empty => **Aggregation**
- GAME takes place in a GAMEWORLD but GAME cannot exist without a Gameworld => **Composition**

Look at the  [the difference between Aggregation and Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Aggregation) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was aware of the difference between aggregation and composition (aggregation being a weaker form of composition) but when it comes to scenarios I sometimes get confused. Thanks to your answer I now have a clearer understanding of the scenario. Thanks again for your help:).

Comment: @user1279780 On StackOverflow, it is not necessary (or recommended) to use comments to thank people. Upvote their answer and, especially, **accept** it.